# Joomla 2.5 website is not visible to the public

Tags: joomla2.5, ubuntu-server

I've just installed a ubuntu server and moved into a website for it but I discovered something crazy.
Once I started the server, I discovered that half of the site was not visible, tried to log in and suddenly it was all there.
Should add that it is a Joomla 2.5 version the site is created in.
I can not find the error, and do not know what to tell the client, why it does what it does.
Can someone be kind and get a suggestion thanks in advance.
Sincerely
/ / Johanna

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you enabled the .htaccess file? Can you access the backend

Comment: Hi, yes i can access the backend.
What do u mean whit the htaccess file?

Comment: This is solved, i have found the error, it was server permissions i have forgot to change :D